# Passing date from Kendo DatePickerFor to model with Ajax.BeginForm()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am passing date from view to controller in ASP.NET MVC 5 using kendo datepickerfor. The issue is that, kendo datepickerfor is passing default date i.e:- 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM to controller and not passing the selected date.

Model(Bill.cs)

```
public DateTime BillTransactionDate { get; set; }
```

View (Bill.cshtml)

```
      @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_SaveManualBillUpload", "Bill",null, new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "return OnBillTransBegin()", HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnBillTranSuccess" }, new { @id = "frmBillTransaction" }))
{
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.BillTransactionDate).Format("MM/dd/yyyy").HtmlAttributes(new {data_toggle = "tooltip",
                                            data_placement = "bottom", data_trigger = "focus", title = MW.Resource.Resources.HelpTransactionDate })
                                            )}
```

BillController

```
   public ActionResult _SaveManualBillUpload(BillTransactionDetail TransactionDetailModel)
    {}
```

Here in TransactionDetailModel, I am getting default value for kendo datepickerfor instead of selected date from kendo datepickerfor. If I select date less than 12 then i get proper selected date, but for dates greater than 12,the kendo is passing date as 
1/1/0001 to controller.Can anyone point out the mistake ?  [KendoErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vVPA.png)

Comment: No, it means that nothing is being passed (and the property is initialized to its default value)

Comment: @StephenMuecke If i am selecting date less than 12, then it is passing proper date, but if I am passing date greater than 12, then it is passing default value and **ModelState.IsValid** is false. I am getting following error for **The value '11/30/2016' is not valid for BillTransactionDate**.seems some issue with date format.

Comment: Then the culture on your server does not match the format your specifying  in the Kendo options (`MM/dd/yyyy`). I assume your server culture is `dd/MM/yyy`

Comment: Yeah, it is dd/MM/yyyy. But if i specify this format in kendo datepicker, then my **jquery.validate.min.js** or ** jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js** or **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js**  throw exception that, date format is not correct. i dont know which of this js file is validating date.

Comment: That because `jquery.validate.js` validates dates based on `MM/dd/yyyy` format. You need to reconfigure the validator.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your help. I will try it out and post, if it is solving my problem

Comment: You should edit your question to explain what the real issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got my answer, if someone has similar problems.
Just set a date culture,where you fill your model from kendo datepicker in controller.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us");
```

Hope it helps!